# AWS best practice: shall I have a NAT gateway in each AZ?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nat, subnet, availability-zone

Since NAT gateway only have redundancy within a single AZ, if I want to have a public/private pair of subnets in every AZ for the purpose of multi-AZ redundancy, I should have a NAT gateway in every AZ, shouldn't I?

Otherwise, if I have only one NAT, if the AZ goes down, all the subnets in all AZs go down with it, thus defeating the purpose of this multi-AZ deployment.

Am I right or wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes, ideally you would have one NAT gateway per Availability Zone (AZ).

AWS documents this advice at [Comparison of NAT Instances and NAT Gateways](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-nat-comparison.html):

> Highly available: NAT gateways in each Availability Zone are implemented with redundancy. Create a NAT gateway in each Availability Zone to ensure zone-independent architecture.

A single NAT gateway in a single AZ has redundancy within that AZ only, so if there were zonal issues then instances in other AZs would have no route to the internet.

Note: there are per hour charges for each NAT gateway as well as per GB data processed (see [VPC Pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/vpc/pricing/)). See [How can I reduce data transfer charges for my NAT gateway?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/vpc-reduce-nat-gateway-transfer-costs/)

Answer (score 9):

From the AWS official [NAT Gateway doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-gateway.html#nat-gateway-basics):

> If you have resources in multiple Availability Zones and they share
>   one NAT gateway, in the event that the NAT gateway's Availability Zone
>   is down, resources in the other Availability Zones lose internet
>   access, To create an Availability Zone-independent architecture,
>   create a NAT gateway in each Availability Zone and configure your
>   routing to ensure that resources use the NAT gateway in the same
>   Availability Zone.

The NAT Gateway enables outgoing Internet connectivity for a private subnet. It is important to note that you need to create a NAT Gateway for every Availability Zone that you have created private subnets to achieve high availability.

The described network architecture consisting of public subnets, private subnets, and HA NAT gateways

[image]

#### Considerations

- If keeping costs to a minimum is essential, the baseline costs of $32.00 per month per NAT Gateway could be a show stopper. When using three AZs, you will pay $96.00 per month for three NAT Gateways.
- The NAT Gateway also increases costs for outbound traffic. You have to pay a premium of $0.045 per GB flowing from a private subnet to the Internet. That’s raising the costs for outgoing traffic by 50%.

#### Extra Points!

- Terraform Infra as Code module [simple VPC example](https://github.com/binbashar/terraform-aws-vpc/tree/master/examples/simple-vpc)

```
...

 azs             = ["us-east-1a", "us-east-1b", "us-east-1c"]
 private_subnets = ["10.0.1.0/24", "10.0.2.0/24", "10.0.3.0/24"]
 public_subnets  = ["10.0.101.0/24", "10.0.102.0/24", "10.0.103.0/24"]

 enable_nat_gateway = true
 single_nat_gateway = false # to get 1 NGW x AZ

...
```

---

**Ref Link:** https://cloudonaut.io/advanved-aws-networking-pitfalls-that-you-should-avoid/

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of 3 factors:

1. Redundancy requirements and implications.

   - If there is an interruption to NAT service in a given AZ how much impact can your application tolerate?
   - What is the likelihood of an interruption to more than one AZ being something other than an interruption affecting the entire region?
   - Redundant NATGWs do not fully insulate you from service interruptions. When a NATGW becomes unavailable all connections through that NATGW will be terminated. Similarly when that NATGW comes back *the connections will be terminated again as the underlying routing will change back*.
2. Per-NATGW cost.

   - Each NATGW currently costs about USD$32.40/mo
3. Intra-AZ bandwidth cost.

   - If you need to egress traffic via a NATGW that is not in the same AZ you will incur intra-AZ bandwidth costs of USD$0.01/GB in addition to the USD$0.045/GB NATGW bandwidth.

Answer (score 0):

**Depends on your use case.**

Before creating a NAT GTW in each AZ, I would consider the specific use case and amount of traffic you use.

I suggest to read [this great SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525573/can-a-single-nat-gateway-span-across-multiple-az):

> Amazon EC2 instances in private subnets can use a NAT Gateway as
> follows:
>
> - The NAT Gateway is launched in a public subnet in the same VPC.
> - The Route Table for the private subnet(s) require an additional entry that
>   directs all Internet-bound traffic (0.0.0.0/0) to the NAT Gateway.

...

---

(*) The basic and trivial use case is that for DEV environment, you don't need 3 NAT GTW. You can even run in one AZ, because availability is more relevant for Production (and for Staging if it is decided that they should be a mirror of each other).