# Configure Multiple NAT gateways

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-vpc, nat

I have two public & private subnets across two AZs. I want to create a NAT in both public subnets. How do I route my private route table to use both NATs? Case three in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59525573/can-a-single-nat-gateway-span-across-multiple-az) accepted answer. I know it's possible but I'm unsure on how to implement it. Should the destination cidr_block be the public subnet's cidr block? I also tried `0.0.0.0/0` and errored out.

```
resource "aws_route" "r" {
  count                     = length(aws_nat_gateway.this)
  route_table_id            = aws_vpc.vpc.default_route_table_id
  destination_cidr_block    = "aws_subnet.public_subnets.${count.index}.cidr_block"
  nat_gateway_id            = "aws_nat_gateway.this.${count.index}.id"
  depends_on                = [aws_vpc.vpc,aws_subnet.public_subnets,aws_nat_gateway.this]
}
```

When I tried `0.0.0.0/0`

`error creating Route in Route Table (rtb-059eee10e310ade77) with destination (0.0.0.0/0): RouteAlreadyExists: The route identified by 0.0.0.0/0 already exists.`

[image]

Comment: What errors do you get exactly? Also what is `aws_nat_gateway.this`?

Comment: I suggest using the official AWS VPC module for Terraform: https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws/latest or at least looking at the source code of that module to help you learn Terraform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you need to have a separate route table for each private subnet.

Long answer: I would start by defining a map that contains configuration for each availability zone. I avoid `count` in modern Terraform configs because it's too easy to cause incompatibilities down the road (especially if you're using it to index an array).

```
locals {
  subnets = {
    "1a" = { "public_cidr": "172.31.0.0/24", private_cidr: "172.31.1.0/24" }
    "1b" = { "public_cidr": "172.31.2.0/24", private_cidr: "172.31.3.0/24" }
  }
}
```

Now, you can use `for_each` to create public and private subnets for each of these availability zones:

```
resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each    = local.subnets
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.example.id
  cidr_block  = each.value["public_cidr"]
  tags = {
    Name      = "public-${each.key}"
  }
}

resource "aws_subnet" "private" {
  for_each    = local.subnets
  vpc_id      = aws_vpc.example.id
  cidr_block  = each.value["private_cidr"]
  tags = {
    Name      = "private-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

You can associate the public subnets with the default route table (which must have a route to the Internet Gateway). Personally, I prefer creating my own public route table, rather than updating the default.

Next, you'll need to create a NAT Gateway in each public subnet:

```
resource "aws_nat_gateway" "example" {
  depends_on    = [aws_internet_gateway.example]
  for_each      = local.subnets
  allocation_id = aws_eip.nat_ip[each.key].id
  subnet_id     = aws_subnet.public[each.key].id

  tags = {
    Name        = "nat-${each.key}"
  }
}
```

And now the important part: each private subnet needs its own route table, which references the NAT Gateway specific to its availability zone.

```
resource "aws_route_table" "private" {
  for_each          = local.subnets
  vpc_id            = aws_vpc.example.id

  route {
    cidr_block      = "0.0.0.0/0"
    nat_gateway_id  = aws_nat_gateway.example[each.key].id
  }

  tags = {
    Name            = "private-${each.key}"
  }
}


resource "aws_route_table_association" "private" {
  for_each       = local.subnets
  subnet_id      = aws_subnet.private[each.key].id
  route_table_id = aws_route_table.private[each.key].id
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I initially missed that small detail of a using a route table per private subnet. Also, is there a reason why you defined subnets in local instead of a variable?

Comment: I use locals for "hardcoded" and derived configuration, variables for things that I expect to be passed in. You certainly could use a variable in this place, and provide defaults that match the configuration I've shown. However, I don't see a reason to do that unless you're provisioning multiple VPCs _with different CIDRs._ And if you're not doing that, exposing a variable increases the risk both of configurations that aren't fully source-controlled, as well as accidental changes. Which in the case of a VPC could be catastrophic.